# BeautifulSoup4 parsing html

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to grab all the High school names along with their city from this website.  Using BeautifulSoup4.  I added the none working code below.  Thanks so much.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_high_schools_in_Texas

```
import urllib2
bs4 import BeautifulSoup

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-again','Mozilla/5.0' ) ]

url = ("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_high_schools_in_Texas")

ourUrl = opener.open(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(ourUrl)

print get_text(soup.find_all('il'))
```

! [html] (http://i1074.photobucket.com/albums/w402/phillipjones2/Screenshot2014-08-07at53445PM_zpsebe195cb.png)

Comment: Can you please supply more information? Mainly: What is wrong with the output you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous errors in your program. Below is a working one that should serve as a base for additional optimization.

```
import requests # much better than using urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # you forgot the `from`

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_high_schools_in_Texas" 
# you don't need () around it
r = requests.get(url) 
# does everything all at once, no need to call `opener` and `read()`
contents = r.text # get the HTML contents of the page

soup = BeautifulSoup(contents)
for item in soup.find_all('li'): # 'li' and 'il' are different things...
    print item.get_text()        # you need to iterate over all the elements
                                 # found by `find_all()`
```

And that's it. This will get you the text of every `<li>...</li>` item on the page. As you'll see when you run the program, there are a lot of irrelevant results, such as the table of contents, the menu items on the left side, the footer, etc. I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to get just the names of the schools, and separate out county names and other cruft.

For reference, have a good read through the BS [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). They'll answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: I got the following error when I ran the code:Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "grapWebpage2.py", line 12, in <module>
        print BeautifulSoup.get_text(item) 
    TypeError: unbound method get_text() must be called with      BeautifulSoup instance as first argument (got Tag instance instead)

Comment: I use python 2.7.  furthermore.  I was able to get all the text between <li> tags.  that wasn't the question.  I want to know how to dig down and get the text I specified.

Comment: @user3827516 that was not at all clear from your question, as you said your code wasn't working at all (which was true), so my answer dealt with how to get your posted code working. To dig down, you'll have to identify patterns in the HTML which only occur in the school name lists, and not elsewhere. Wikipedia's code is generally quite clean, so this exercise shouldn't be too complex.